# Use DatePeriod and DateInterval to get certain weekdays within a period of time

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

I need to get certain weekdays within a period of time.
Weekdays can be only one ore more, e.g. only all Mondays or all Mondays, Tuesdays and Wednesdays.

I would like to use [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/de/class.dateperiod.php) together with [DateInterval::createFromDateString](http://php.net/manual/de/dateinterval.createfromdatestring.php)

DateInterval::createFromDateString is accepting [Relative Formats](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php).

How can I pass one or more weekdays as relative formats into DateInterval::createFromDateString. Is this possible at all?

In relative formats I can't find a format "every" that would make it possible to do

```
$i = DateInterval::createFromDateString('every Monday');
```

Comment: Relative formats only go so far. You'll have to write your own logic to get these dates.

Comment: ["Monday"](http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php)

Comment: @John Conde
ok, that's what I thought. Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @Wrikken
Will this give evry Monday within my defined period? And can I pass multiple days like "Monday or Tuesday or Wednesday"?

Comment: Hm, it should according to the docs _"dayname Moves to the next day of this name."_, but it seems to fail miserably here...

Comment: And it wouldn't help you with multiple days needed as well. Might not be ideal for a `DatePeriod`, you may have to resort to just adding a day to a `DateTime` in a for loop, and validating or discarding (`continue;`) certain non-valid dates.

Comment: @Wrikken
Yeah, it is failing here, too. Seems not possible to do this with relative formats. But thanks for trying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to all comments and answers I now know that I cannot pass a relative format like "every Monday" to DateInterval::createFromDateString.

But something like this works for my scenario:

```
$start = new DateTime('2014-11-01');
$end = new DateTime('2014-12-01');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$period = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);
$mydays = array('1', '3', '5');

foreach($period as $date) {
    if(in_array($date->format('N'), $mydays)) {
    //do something for Monday, Wednesday and Friday
    }
}
```